# Python3 not recognized in bash scripts

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi

I removed Python 2.7 from my system and some of my old bash scripts stopped working. The problem was that it was not finding python3. I aliased python to point to python3 in .bashrc and everything works fine at the commandline, but in the bash script I still get the same error "python: command not found".

I made a simple script with the following lines and I get the error for the first line only.
python --version
python3 --version

I could change "python" to "python3", but what else could be doing to avoid making changes in all the scripts?

Thanks.

Comment: Create a symbolic link from python to python3; e.g. `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`.

Comment: Awesome - this works.  Any idea why the alias in .bashrc doesn't work?

Comment: The alias only affects the behavior of the shell (`bash`).  A `#!/usr/bin/python` in an executable script is *actually* interpreted by the OS `exec` syscall ... to decide which interpreter should run the file.

Comment: Aliases are disabled by default in non-interactive shells, and they also don't load ~/.bashrc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an alias. Use a symlink, that's a more generic solution, works for all shells, all users:

(all commands as root user)

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ln -s $(which python3) python
```

If you are on Ubuntu, it's even easier, just install the `python-is-python3` package:

```
apt install python-is-python3
```